# How can I use a different-colored logo on specific pages on my Squarespace site?

Tags: squarespace

Squarespace only allows the usage of one logo, and since the logo on our homepage is white (because of the dark-colored background), this white logo is invisible on every other white page on our site.

I'd like to use a green-colored logo on most pages.

Is there a code-injection that would accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked SquareSpace customer support?